# Crystal: joining two events on the same time

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

I have a report that shows events for refrigerated containers. There are 3 kinds of events only: REEFER_SETTINGS RECORDED which records temperature and UNIT_POWER_CONNECT/DISCONNECT which doesn't. When container is connected/disconnected to power at the same moment two separate events occur: connection (or d/c) and temperature reading:

[image]

Customer would like to remove those redundancy and instead of those two events at same moment have one (connection or disconnection) AND recorded temperature:

```
UNIT_POWER_CONNECT          21/12/2013 10:11        -15
REEFER_SETTINGS_RECORDED    21/12/2013 12:30        -17  
UNIT_POWER_DISCONNECT       21/12/2013 18:30        -16
```

I've tried creating grouping by recording time (by minute) but while indeed it was removing the redundancy the event was selected semi-randomly - either temp selection or connection/dc - and in case of the latter there was still no temperature recorded. Any ideas? I'd prefer to avoid doing union in SQL query (which probably could solve this) since there is already union in it and it would make things pretty complicated. I've tried using NEXT and PREVIOUS crystal functions but without much luck.

EDIT: note about the SQL part:
 There are three tables important for this part of the query: Reefer_records that stores the temperature, service_events that stores all sorts of events (include temperature records but not the temperature itself) and inv_unit that stores physical information about the container. The first two tables are in Many-to-one relationship with inv_unit and when the the temperature recording or connection event occurs data is recorded to both tables - type of event in service_events and temperature in reefer_records. My SQL query in huge shortcut looks like this:

```
SELECT inv_unit.id,
reefer_records.Temp_recorded
reefer_records.Time_recorded
'' as event_type
FROM inv_unit INNER JOIN reefer_records on....

UNION ALL

SELECT inv_unit.id
'' as temp_recorded
srv_events.time_recorded
srv_events.event_type
FROM inv_unit INNER JOIN srv_events on...
```

Full query [is here](http://justpaste.it/dydu)

Comment: Can you show your sql query?

Comment: Can you just ignore where read temp is null?

Comment: If I'll ignore when temp is null then I will loose the connection and disconnection events which I have to keep.

Comment: Can you use a `CASE` statement. like `CASE when Recordingtime = Recordingtime then 'Connect/Disconnect' else event end as event`? Without seeing the query I'm going to have a hard time trying to help you.

Comment: Problem is that query is bit too long for this forum, so I had to put it separate page: [link](http://justpaste.it/dydu)

Comment: Small comment about this query (And reason for already existing union): Three tables are in X M:1 Y 1:M Z relationship - Reefer_records store the temperature recorded but not the event type, srv_events store all sorts of events (including temperature readings) but not the temperature, and both of them are in M:1 relationship with inv_unit which has physical details of container. When temperature is recorded or unit is connected data is written simultaneously to two tables with same time stamp but different content.